# Dropdown Menu No Longer Changes Shopify Product Images?? What Happened?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, shopify, shopify-template

When you click on an item on our shop it no longer changes product images or update price... And come to think of it, the shop doesnt say "Out of stock" when you select a certain out of stock variant anymore either... It's like anything with the drop down no longer works on my shop... Whats going on? We cant seem to figure it out...

Product page: https://kingofthepin.com/collections/enamel-pins/products/animehub-enamel-pin

Answer (score 0):

You've got an uncaught JS error in https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/themes_support/option_selection-ea4f4a242e299f2227b2b8038152223f741e90780c0c766883939e8902542bda.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at new Shopify.SingleOptionSelector (option_selection-ea4f4a242e299f2227b2b8038152223f741e90780c0c766883939e8902542bda.js:1)
    at Shopify.OptionSelectors.buildSelectors (option_selection-ea4f4a242e299f2227b2b8038152223f741e90780c0c766883939e8902542bda.js:1)
    at Shopify.OptionSelectors.replaceSelector (option_selection-ea4f4a242e299f2227b2b8038152223f741e90780c0c766883939e8902542bda.js:1)
    at new Shopify.OptionSelectors (option_selection-ea4f4a242e299f2227b2b8038152223f741e90780c0c766883939e8902542bda.js:1)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (theme.js?13924364935478740494:793)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at new Product (theme.js?13924364935478740494:792)
    at Sections._createInstance (theme.js?13924364935478740494:538)
    at Sections.<anonymous> (theme.js?13924364935478740494:616)
```

Looks like you're using some Bold Product Options app.  That might be interfering with whatever your theme's JS is expecting.

Fixing the problem is going to require more information, most likely access to your Shopify store's theme files, to try and diagnose where the problem is.  But, at least this answers the "why doesn't X work any more" question.

Comment: Hey dossy, Thanks for your response! Are the theme files something i can send you to help me diagnose whats going on here? I dont have Bold Product options installed, but i do have 2 other apps by bold installed. I have "Recurring Orders & Subscription Box App" & "Sales Motivator" both by Bold.

Comment: @JStormThaKid I'd start by contacting Bold's support, this is probably a FAQ for them.

Comment: Sounds great, will do. Lastly, which part of the error pointed you in the direction of Bold?

Comment: @JStormThaKid the problem seems to be related to product option data, and you have some Bold app that's modifying the product option data, so I just connected the dots.

Comment: Also, seeing more JS errors now: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'v9359985967151' of undefined` - this looks like an outdated Bold Recurring Orders Liquid file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input @dossy. This is such a weird issue. I’ll keep digging and return with any finds.